# Loop para Somar valores de um db

Tags: php, loop, phpmyadmin

Estou fazendo um sistema de controle financeiro, e fiz um loop while para pegar os dados dos clientes de um db e mostra-los em uma tabela. O que quero fazer é pegar os valores da coluna "PREÇO" e somar, para dar o valor do total de saldos. Vou colocar apenas a parte do código relevante:

```
    <?php
                        $seleciona="select * from receitas order by nome";
                        $sql=mysqli_query($con,$seleciona);
                        while ($inf=mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
                                $cliente=$inf[0];
                                $data=$inf[1];
                                $horario=$inf[2];
                                $preco=$inf[3];
                                $servico=$inf[4];

                    echo"           
                              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$cliente</td>
                              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$data</td>
                              <td>$horario</td>
                              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$preco</td>
                              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$servico</td>
                            </tr>
                            ";}

                ?>
```

O que quero fazer agora é um loop para pegar os valores da variavel "$preco" e somar para colocar o resultado da soma de todos os valores como o total de receitas.

Comment: E que tipo de dados tem na coluna preços?

Comment: Foi o que eu pensei no inicio, eu fiz exatamente assim: $total=$preco+$inf[3]; mas o problema é que ele não soma em loop, mas apenas os dois primeiros valores

Answer (score 1):

O correto é  `$total=$total+$inf[3];` ou `$total=$total+$preco;`

```
<?php
     $total=0;
     $seleciona="select * from receitas order by nome";
     $sql=mysqli_query($con,$seleciona);
     while ($inf=mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
         $cliente=$inf[0];
         $data=$inf[1];
         $horario=$inf[2];
         $preco=$inf[3];

         $total=$total+$inf[3];

         $servico=$inf[4];

           echo"           
              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$cliente</td>
              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$data</td>
              <td>$horario</td>
              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$preco</td>
              <td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>$servico</td>
              </tr>
          ";}

?>
```

> Quando você faz `$total=$preco+$inf[3];` conforme dito no comentário, a cada iteração do loop ele está somando `$preco`, que nada mais é do que  `$inf[3]`,  com `$inf[3]` que são os mesmos valores. No final do loop o resultado é o dobro do ultimo valor retornado da tabela.

```
 $preco=$inf[3];
 $total=$preco+$inf[3];

                 preco    $total=$preco+$inf[3];
 ponteiro ->     20.00    20.00 + 20.00 = 40.00
                 30.00
                 40.00
                 .....

                 preco    $total=$preco+$inf[3];
                 20.00       
 ponteiro ->     30.00    30.00 + 30.00 = 60.00 
                 40.00
                 .....
```

> **Já com** `$total=$total+$inf[3];`

```
                 preco    $total=$total+$inf[3];
 ponteiro ->     20.00      0 + 20.00 = 40.00
                 30.00
                 40.00
                 .....

                 preco    $total=$total+$inf[3];
                 20.00       
 ponteiro ->     30.00     40.00 + 30.00 = 70.00 
                 40.00
                 .....

                 preco    $total=$total+$inf[3];
                 20.00       
                 30.00     
 ponteiro ->     40.00     70.00 + 40.00 = 110.00 
                 .....
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! É incrível como um mínimo detalhe que passa despercebido na lógica afeta todo o resto do sistema. Vlw!